# how do I add a leading zero to a column?

Tags: mysql

So I am importing a customer table and the date values are missing the leading zero for the month, so month column has a value of 2 instead of 02. How can I add a leading zero to the effected dates without adding a zero to dates where the leading zero is no issue? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What are the data types of the columns?

Comment: Why no using a date column for... storing dates?

Comment: If the datatype is an integer, which I am assuming it is, because there were 0 details given, this is not possible to do.

Comment: Do you have other date-related columns in the table you are importing? Would you be able to create a proper date field as the others are suggesting?

Comment: the columns are varchar, and my existing column structure is working great for how I am using the data in this table. My issue is with the data table I am importing, which I have no control over :-(. But I got it worked out thanks  A cat named Midnight :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try `select right(concat('0', <YourMonth>), 2)`.

Alternatively you could use the MySQL [LPAD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) function, but this is a handy technique to know that you can also use in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

If you're storing dates, you should be storing them into a date column in MySQL. It'll pad appropriately, and you'll be able to do proper date-based queries on the data like `WHERE BETWEEN` or using MySQL's `INTERVAL` math.